# Python: How to load application into full screen with no toolbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I had been using the following code in my python application to load it full screen without any top tool bar.

```
#  uncomment these 3 lines to load it full screen no menu bar
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.wm_state('normal') #  normal, iconic, withdrawn
root.overrideredirect(True)

#  this will keep the window on top
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
```

I think this might be call kiosk mode?  Now in my application I have two windows that open up at different times that require user response. Using the settings above second windows are never visible. I tried changing this to false....

```
root.attributes('-topmost', False)
```

... but that still doesn't do it.

How can I load my application in kiosk mode but still have my child windows open on top if the app so the user can access the option.

Comment: If you are using `tkinter`, you can call `w.lift()` on the second window IIRC

Comment: One window is generated with a quit button that does call a tkMessageBox.askyesno. The second window is a tkColorChooser window.  I will look at the lift() to see if that works. Thanks.